# Calculating average daily volume giving incorrect data (Pine v5)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to create a custom volume script and have calculated the last 30 days volume average using, what I think is the correct code:

```
dailyLookback = input(30, "Daily Lookback", group = "Vol Settings", inline = "Volume Settings")

dVol = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", volume)
dAvgVol = math.sum(dVol[1], dailyLookback) / dailyLookback
```

The data is then plotted in a table column but the calculated result is different on all time frames and none are the correct value. Is there a problem with the code?

Comment: What timeframe are you on and what is your intention with dVol[1] in math.sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `dVol[1]`. You cannot use the history reference operator to access historical data of the higher timeframe bars.

`dVol[1]` refers to `dVol`'s previous value on your chart's timeframe. That would still be the same as `dVol` unless it is a new bar on the higher timeframe.

What you need to do is, calculate the average volume based on your chart's timeframe and pass this expression to the `security()` function.

```
avgVol = ta.sma(volume, dailyLookback)
dAvgVol = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", avgVol[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```